# Project Euler/Python: find sum of multiples of 3 and 5. Program not proceeding past input

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm new to programming and i'm doing the Project Euler challenges to give me a reason to learn.

Find below my very simple python code

```
x = 1                       
thirdDivide = 0             
fifthDivide=0     
total = 0                   

print('Enter the max value')

maxValue = input()

while (x != maxValue):
    thirdDivide = x / 3
    fifthDivide = x / 5
    if (thirdDivide).is_integer():
        total = total + x
        x = x + 1
    elif (fifthDivide).is_integer():
        total = total + x
        x = x + 1

print ("The sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 between 0 and " + maxValue + " is " + total)
```

When I run it it asks for my max value, then ceases doing anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Try printing inside the while loop and you should see the issue. In particular if you enter `2` as an input it will loop infinitely.

Comment: Your program goes into infinit loop. x is never incremented. maxValue is a string, not number.

Comment: Are you using Python 3? This code won't work as expected with Python 2, as `2/3` is `0` in v2.

Comment: What is `is_integer()`?

Comment: FYI There used to be a [tag:project-euler] tag but [it was controversially deleted in 2014](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler). In the opinion of many, this was a terrible idea and guarantees that duplicates will forever be posted here, and you won't be able to easily find them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in Python 3, the fixes for using strings instead of floats, or floats instead of strings, infite loop is following:

```
x = 1
thirdDivide = 0
fifthDivide=0
total = 0

maxValue = float(input('Enter the max value: '))

while (x != maxValue):
    thirdDivide = x / 3
    fifthDivide = x / 5
    if (thirdDivide).is_integer():
        total = total + x
    elif (fifthDivide).is_integer():
        total = total + x
    x = x + 1

print("The sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 between 0 and " + str(maxValue) + " is " + str(total))
```

Note, I dont check for correctness of your algoritm and whether it calculates what it is supposed to do. But now it produces some results and compiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with a [functional approach](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html) using `filter` and `reduce`:

```
def f(acc, v): return acc + v


def g(x): return x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0


print reduce(f, filter(g, range(1000)))
```

How it works:

- [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter): takes two arguments:

  1. The first is a function `g` applied for every element of `range(1000)`. `g` takes one argument `x` and check `if` is multiple of `3` or `5` (checking the remainder of the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operation `%`).
  2. The second is the [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) from `0` to `1000`.
- [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce): takes two arguments:

  1. The first is a function `f` that takes two arguments: an accumulator `acc` and a variable `v` that represents the current element in the list.
  2. The second argument is the filtered [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) returned before by `filter`.

Output:

- with `range(10)` = `23`
- with `range(1000)` = `233168`

Using [lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) functions (same logic just different syntax):

```
print reduce(lambda acc, v: acc + v, filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0, range(1000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You only increment x if thirdDivide.is_integer() or fifthDivide.is_integer() are true.  So if neither it true, you'll just loop infinitely on the same value of x.

Answer (score 0):

If neither `thirdDivide` nor `fifthDivide` is an integer, `x` is never updated -- you enter an infinite loop.  You need to make sure you have a "base case" so that the iteration variable is *always* changing.  Here's a slightly cleaner algorithm:

```
total = 0
for i in range(0, x):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        total += i
```

I think you'll find that for most iteration, `for` loops are easier to reason about.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

As many said before, you are stuck in an infinite loop with x not being incremented. If you added a "else" statement at the end and printed the output you could see what they are talking about. You can do this in one line of code.

```
print(sum(x for x in range(maxValue) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0))
```